# Php Laravel date array loop logic

Tags: php, arrays, loops, date, laravel

Im working on a project that requires to schedule events with the ability to repeat them for a specific length of time. My goal is to pass the initial date from the form and increment it by 7 so that the date will land on the same weekday for the number of iterations selected. I have accounted for dates that stretch into new months and new years. However towards the end of the loop the dates get off. An example of the error :

**Error:**

```
    array:16 [
  0 => "2016-07-05"
  1 => "2016-07-12"
  2 => "2016-07-19"
  3 => "2016-07-26"
  4 => "2016-08-02"
  5 => "2016-08-09"
  6 => "2016-08-16"
  7 => "2016-08-23"
  8 => "2016-08-30"
  9 => "2016-09-06"
  10 => "2016-09-13"
  11 => "2016-09-20"
  12 => "2016-09-27"
  13 => "2016-10-03" --> should be 10-04
  14 => "2016-10-10" --> should be 10-11
  15 => "2016-10-17" --> should be 10-18
]
```

**another example:**

```
array:16 [
  0 => "2016-12-01"
  1 => "2016-12-08"
  2 => "2016-12-15"
  3 => "2016-12-22"
  4 => "2016-12-29"
  5 => "2017-01-05"
  6 => "2017-01-12"
  7 => "2017-01-19"
  8 => "2017-01-26"
  9 => "2017-02-02"
  10 => "2017-02-09"
  11 => "2017-02-16"
  12 => "2017-02-23"
  13 => "2017-03-02"
  14 => "2017-03-06" --> should be 03-09
  15 => "2017-03-13" --> should be 03-16
]
```

**Here is the function I made:**

First I pass the request from the controller to the model.  Then i take the initial date and break it into initial year, month and day. Now im working on the weekly repeat for the limit of classes available. I increment the initial day by 7 taking to account if it goes past the number of days in that month and incrementing that month and year when needed.  Every date I make is pushed into the array above. Can you help find the missing step which is making the dates get off at towards the end of the loop?

```
    public static function repeat_array($request){
    $repeat = $request->get('repeat_event');
    $iteration = $request->get('repeat_iteration');
    $initial = $request->get('date');


    $mySets = Packages::my_sets();
    $myReps = Packages::my_reps();
    $initial_Y = date('Y',strtotime($initial));
    $initial_M = date('m',strtotime($initial));
    $initial_D = date('d',strtotime($initial));

    $days_in_month = date('t',strtotime($initial_Y.'-'.$initial_M.'-01'));
    $current_count = CalenderEvents::class_count();

    $class_limit = $mySets*$myReps;


    if($current_count >= $class_limit){
        dd('too many');
    } else{
        if($repeat == 'weekly'){
            if($iteration == 'Null'){
                $weekly_array = [];
                $loop_date = $initial_D;
                $loop_month = $initial_M;
                $loop_year = $initial_Y;
                for($i = 0; $i < $class_limit; $i++){   -> //loop through the dates until limit is reached.
                    if($i == 0){   --> push the initial date as the first value in array. 
                        array_push($weekly_array, $initial);
                    } else{     --> increment the day by 7. 

                        $loop_date = $loop_date + 7;

                    if ($loop_date > $days_in_month){   --> //when the dates surpasses the amount of days in the month increment the month and subtract 30 from the total to get correct date. 

                            $loop_date = $loop_date - 30;
                            $loop_month++;

                        if($loop_month > 12){

                            $loop_month = 1;
                            $loop_year++;
                            $loop_date = $loop_date - 1;

                                $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($loop_year.'-'.$loop_month.'-'.$loop_date));

                                array_push($weekly_array, $date);

                            } else{

                                $loop_date = $loop_date - 1;

                                $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($loop_year.'-'.$loop_month.'-'.$loop_date));

                                array_push($weekly_array, $date);
                            }

                        } else{

                            $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($loop_year.'-'.$loop_month.'-'.$loop_date));

                            array_push($weekly_array, $date);

                        }
                    }
                }
                dd($weekly_array);
            }
        }
        $remainder = $class_limit - $current_count;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php) with dates in php to make interpolate dates.

Init your date with a DateTime class

```
$date = new DateTime($initial)
```

keep the date formatted in you array

```
$weekly_array[] = $date->format('Y-m-d')
```

and for each iteration

```
$date = $date->modify('+1 week');
$weekly_array[] = $date->format('Y-m-d')
```

This handles well the passage to the next year as shown in that [ideone example](https://ideone.com/AmK6Al).

Comment: This is AMAZING! This is so simple and easy to understand +1 all day!

Comment: I was enthusiastic as you when I first discovered about that feature of php.